# How to distinguish if a file or folder is being dragged prior to it being dropped?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, directory

I am trying to detect if a folder or a file is dragged in the **`dragover`** or **`dragenter`** events.

#### For example:

In the `ondrop` event, there is an argument called `MouseEvent`, which has a field named `dataTransfer`, where are listed files (`.files`) or items (`.items`), depending on the browser, and I can read that in both [Chrome](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/07/Drag-and-drop-a-folder-onto-Chrome-now-available) and [Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378708/how-to-distinguish-folders-and-files-drag-and-drop-ajax-upload-in-firefox). However, for the `dragover` and `dragenter` events those fields (`.files` and `.items`) are empty. The problem is that **I need that information while dragging, not dropping**.

*NOTE: For both files and folders `event.dataTransfer.types[i] === "Files"` is `true`.*

#### Background Research

I found [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9536533/2982225) to partially fit for my question:

> WebKit, and hence Chrome, is quite restrictive on when you can call `getData`. You're not allowed to do it inside `dragstart` or `dragover`. I think this is the canonical bug.

But that answer is from 2012, and **I can't find actual updated information on the topic**, so I am looking for updated information on this.

Comment: I found the fit answer for my question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534677/html5-drag-and-drop-getdata-only-works-on-drop-event-in-chrome?rq=1) but it's 2012 year, and I can't find an actual info(

Comment: A minimal working example that clarifies or demonstrates the problem might help people provide quality answers.

Comment: [The meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267993)

Comment: My guess is you simply can't do this: what if I am dragging a file or folder over my browser window to something unrelated: I wouldn't want a random website to glean any information about the content of what I am dragging if it isn't the final target.

Comment: Yes! Info about content file should not be available while dragging due to security. But we know the type of dragging element (file or dom element). So, if many browsers does not support folder dnd, so we have right to know file or folder is it.

Comment: @KristinaKurshakova You should do the right thing and accept the answer below. Marco provided a high-quality answer.

Comment: @KrisKu how can we detect if it's a file or a folder? That's what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 120):

**TL;DR you can't.**

<sup>If you're wondering why this question still hasn't got an accepted answer, you can read [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267993) created by OP, and [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283712/3889449).</sup>

## File `drag`/`drop` in HTML5

I made some research in different pieces of documentation for this topic and tested it by myself on various browsers, so I decided to summarize all I know about drag and drop of files here.

### Dragging

When you drag a file you can use some listeners, such as:

- `dragenter`
- `dragover`
- `dragend`
- `dragleave`

Given that these are `drag` events, the `files` property of `event.dataTransfer` will either have `length == 0` or be empty (`null`).

#### You *can't* read files details in a drag event and you *can't* check if they are folders. This is not a bug, it's a security feature.

Imagine you could read files on a drag event: you would be able to read everything even if the user doesn't want to upload files to your site. It would make no sense, seriously. Imagine you are dragging a file from your desktop to another folder and you accidentally drag it through a web page: now the web page reads your file and stores your personal information on its server... **that would be a huge security flaw.**

However, you will still be able to detect whether the user is dragging files (and by files I mean folders too, because folders are files) or not by iterating over the array `event.dataTransfer.types`. You can create a function that checks if the drag event contains files, and then call it in the event handler.

Example:

```
function containsFiles(event) {
    if (event.dataTransfer.types) {
        for (var i=0; i<event.dataTransfer.types.length; i++) {
            if (event.dataTransfer.types[i] == "Files") {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (containsFiles(e)) {
        // The drag event contains files
        // Do something
    } else {
        // The drag event doesn't contain files
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

### Dropping

When you drop a file into the drop `<div>` (or whatever element you're using as dropzone), you will use a listener for the event `drop` to read some file properties such as name, size, type and last modification date.

You can use euristics to ***try detecting*** if a file is a folder or not.

#### Heuristic #1

Use [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) or `webkitGetAsEntry()` as suggested in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53414629/3889449). A `FileReader` instance will emit an `error` event if trying to read a folder (for example with `reader.readAsBinaryString(e.dataTransfer.files[i])`.

**Problem**: using `FileReader` effectively means reading the file. For large files, this can cause problems!

#### Heuristic #2

Check if the file has `type === ""` and its size is a multiple of 4096 (`size % 4096 === 0`).

**Problem**: this method doesn't give you absolute certainty that a file is a folder: it might be a file without extension and with a size of 0 or exactly N x 4096B. Furthermore, as noted in the comments below for example, not all platforms have folders with a `.size` multiple of 4096. For example, one user reports a `size` of `928` for a folder on macOS.

```
function handleDrop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var files = e.dataTransfer.files;

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) { // iterate in the files dropped
        if (!f.type === "" && f.size % 4096 === 0) {
            // The file might be a folder
            // Do something
        } else {
            // The file is not a folder
            // Do something else
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Working examples

Here are some working examples to see what I said above in action and test it by yourself. Before running them, make sure that your browser [supports drag and drop features](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dragndrop). Have fun:

- [File drop display info](http://jsfiddle.net/MeBeiM/k6dreheu) (made by me)
- [File/folder recognize using Heuristic #2](http://jsfiddle.net/MeBeiM/rnjpbhhg) (made by me)
- [File drag detect](http://jsfiddle.net/xseFs/43) (from css-tricks)

Comment: As I write in my question, I need that info while dragging (dragover and dragenter events), not drop.

Comment: Answer edited. This is the best I can do. Im sorry, but it looks like you **can't** read files on `drag` events.

Comment: Thanks, but also as I write `event.dataTransfer.types[i] == "Files"` is true for folder and file.

Comment: I know. My answer to your question is that you really **can't** check if a file is a folder on a drag event. I'm sorry.

Comment: +1 Do you have sources for your two statements concerning the detection of folders? I don't think the folder size is guaranteed by any specification; it's rather a heuristic value, isn't it?

Comment: The system represents folders in blocks of 4KiB, and yes that's actually an heuristic value, there isn't an official method to distinguish a file from a folder.

Comment: On Chrome 39.0.2171.99 for local files, you *can* view `dataTransfer` on drag events now, specifically `ondragenter` and `ondragover`.

Comment: @bryc actually, If you pay attantion and read my answer carefully, I'm saying: "the `files` property of `event.dataTransfer` will either have `length == 0` or be empty (`null`)". So, yes, **`dataTransfer` always exists, but `dataTransfer.files` doesn't**.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I am talking about a specific case of local files on Chrome where `dataTransfer.files` is available at the client side on drag events. That has nothing to contradict your statement

Comment: Seems you can now detect files and folders via the `.webkitGetAsEntry()` method on the file. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/07/Drag-and-drop-a-folder-onto-Chrome-now-available

Comment: That's only webkit by the way

Comment: While 4096*N (N>=0) is a generally used for directory size, other sizes may be present also (see this: https://superuser.com/a/142905)

Comment: Dropped an empty folder named `test.jpeg` in the second example provided, detected as a file.

Comment: @S.D. that's probably because of the "known issue" that folders can't really be recognized for sure without using some heuristic like the one I explained above :\

Comment: @MarcoBonelli There is one other way: `FileReader` does nothing for directories, no `load` or `error` events. But that works for small files only.

Comment: I’m on macOS 10.15.6 and the `size` values for two different folders are `928` and `992`, so it definitely can’t be trusted.

Comment: `event.dataTransfer?.types.includes('Files')`  works fine with TS

Comment: Update from 2022: This answer is no longer correct, apparently browser behaviour has changed.
`console.log([...e.dataTransfer.items].map(v => v.kind));` does indeed print `["file"]` during drag events.

Comment: @Stefnotch this answer is still correct. The issue is not detecting whether files are being dragged or not. It is detecting whether those files being dragged are files or folders. This is still **not** possible. You will get `.kind === "file"` for both files and directories.

Answer (score 3):

This is work on Dropping -on drop event- (please note that this doesn't work on dragover event):

```
isDraggedItemIsFile = function(e) {
// handle FF
if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length == 0) {
    return false;
}
// handle Chrome
if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items) {
    if (typeof (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items[0].webkitGetAsEntry) == "function") {
        return e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items[0].webkitGetAsEntry().isFile;
    } else if (typeof (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items[0].getAsEntry) == "function") {
        return e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items[0].getAsEntry().isFile;
    }
}
return true;
};

$forms.on('drop', function(e) {
        if (isDraggedItemIsFile(e)) {
            // do something if file
        } else{
           // is directory
        }
    });
```

Tested on FF V49, Chrome V55, Edge V25

Comment: Exactly what the OP **is not** looking for. Incorrect, unrelated, confusionary, browser-specific and jQuery based.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same on Safari?

Answer (score 3):

For **dropping**, you can separate files from folders by using `FileReader` or with `webkitGetAsEntry()`.

The `webkitGetAsEntry()` is not supported by IE11, so keep that in mind!

The code will look like:

```
 onDrop(event) {
    let files = event.dataTransfer ? event.dataTransfer.files : 'null';

    for(let i = 0, file; file = files[i]; i++) {
       var reader = new FileReader();

       reader.onload = function (e) {
           console.log('it is a file!');
       };
       reader.onerror = function (e) {
          console.log('it is a folder!');
       };

       reader.readAsText(file);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you might have missed the part of the question that describes how he needs this info during drag over and drag enter, the call to "webkitGetAsEntry()" returns null during theese two events.

Comment: But still very helpfull, because now I know how to identify real files in general. I'll use this in my uploader component, thanks a lot ; )

Comment: For those using this method, if user is using a big file then RileReader approach can be very heavy on the client.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the entire Mimetype of the thing being *dragged* over my page. Mimetype appears to be blank for folders, so maybe you can distinguish it that way.

Partial code (extracted from React):

```
function handleDragOver(ev: DragEvent) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.dataTransfer!.dropEffect = 'copy';
    console.log(Array.from(ev.dataTransfer.items).map(i => [i.kind,i.type].join('|')).join(', '));
}

document.addEventListener('dragover',handleDragOver);
```

Output looks like:

```
file|image/x-icon, file|image/jpeg, file|application/vnd.ms-excel
```

When I drag 3 files over my page.

Not sure if it only works on localhost, I haven't uploaded this anywhere yet, but it's totally working.

[MDN docs on DataTransferItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem)

Comment: works on Chrome 80 windows 10 not localhost https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/rcwzeu2t/ but any file for which the OS doesn't know the mime type shows up as no mime-type so no way to distinguish folders from files