# How to check if file is a directory React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

Making possibility to upload files to the site but in such a way that folders cannot be uploaded. Wrote a function that checks it.

```
function notADirectory(maybeFile) {    // maybeFile ~ new File()
    if (maybeFile.type !== '') return true;
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onloadend = () => !(reader.error && 
        (reader.error.name === 'NotFoundError' || reader.error.name === 'NotReadableError'))
    reader.readAsBinaryString(maybeFile)
}
```

But there is a `text.psd` photoshop file and for some reason js does not see the type in it - it is empty. Because of this, the function does not work properly.

Is there any other proper way to check file on directory?

Adding `directory="" webkitdirectory=""` into html input is not suitable because there is also possibility to add files on site with `Ctrl + V` and dragging it on page

Comment: Does `<input type="file">` not work? Otherwise you are probably out of luck. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016442/how-to-distinguish-if-a-file-or-folder-is-being-dragged-prior-to-it-being-droppe

Comment: @nlta `<input type="file">` won't work because of dragging file on page. But maybe I can give access to user to upload folder but then "unpack" it?